# ViewerJS not display contents of ODT and ODS files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, documentviewer, document-view

I just start using ViewerJS before 1 hour. I tried it with PDF, ODS, ODT, ODP, TXT, XML files, 
But it only supporting PDF and ODS... All other file formats not opening.
For ODT and ODP it showing loading file on top... but contents are not coming at all.

Code example :

```
<a href="/ViewerJS/#../Sample.odp">odp</a>
        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../Sample_invoice.odt">odt</a>
```

[image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../demodoc.pdf">PDF</a>
        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../Dev_Windows_Phone_Apps_Getting_Started_Guide.pdf">pdf2</a>
        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../sample.ods">ods</a>
        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../StockChart.ods">od2</a>

        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../Sample.odp">odp</a>  <%--loading--%>
        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../Sample-Impress-Template_Bern2014_rtryon.odp">odp2</a> <%--loading--%>
        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../Sample_invoice.odt">odt</a> <%--loading--%>

        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../hotTextInteraction.xml">xml</a> <%--not working--%>
        <a href="/ViewerJS/#../qtiplayerCommon.txt">text</a> <%--not working--%>

        <br />

        <iframe src = "/ViewerJS/#../Sample_invoice.odt" width='400' height='300'></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ViewerJS folder contains following things.

[image]

Do I need to change something, or this is issue ?

Is there any other library which I can use to show documents on web page ? I am using asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

**The first:** What browser did you use? It maybe related to your problem.

**The second:** ViewerJS supports a lot of extension file include PDF, ODS, ODT, ODP, TXT, XML. Check about how you imported the .js file of ViewerJS into your web page?

**The third:** Your code show in this post is very quiet good. Don't worry about it! ^^

Comment: Thanks for giving reply, 
I am using chrome browser. I have changed my question with my code, please look into that, and suggest me something... Thanks

Comment: Think about create <iframe> tag to wrap that files. Maybe it can't resize automatically :)

Comment: Do I need to add any extra js files in viewerJS folder... ?

Comment: No. It's all, mah friend :)

Answer (score 0):

You code fragment looks fine. Since ODS works fine but ODP and ODT do not, there might be something strange with the ODP and ODT files. Can you look in the console log to see what is going on?

I see you already found the issue database at github:
 https://github.com/kogmbh/ViewerJS/issues/145

Please paste output from the console in here or in the issue. If you can upload the ODT and ODP files somewhere that would be helpful.